# Div doesn't resize to fit parent

Tags: css

In a nutshell, I've got a side bar with a collapable navbar and a nested div underneath the navbar.

I want the nested div (set to have scrollable content separately)
to fill the space available at all times, yet I don't want it to overflow into the other areas of the webpage.

```
.scroll{
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

- Max-height
- Min-height
- Height in general has been tried to death.

```
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-right:0px;">
    <div class="navbar-header" style="width:100%; float:none; padding-left:15px;">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>       
    </button>    
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Related topics</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar" style="border:0px;">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="width:100%;">
    <li></li>
    <li class="dropdown" style="float:none;">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" style="float:none;" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Links <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li></li>
    <li><></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li ></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="scroll">
    <Content>
    </div>
```

The main div content either bleeds over and pushes other content down or
the nested div doesn't re-size and goes behind lower content.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kVjA.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the full CSS code. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This has proved tricky.
I've found a project on W3Schools that I've nuked to try and show the exact issue I'm having. I've saved it and here's a link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k18nK1PB7D4r5-3uR_FCYjCQsUDbvOrH/view?usp=sharing

I'm trying to make the section that's scrollable change its height to fill or shrink depending on what the above div content/navbar/collapsable/whatever does.

Comment: Please do not add external links. Please update your question with the relative code. If that link disappears, this question will be useless to future visitors.

Comment: Then no, I cannot give you what you are requesting.
If what I have provided is insufficient then so be it, I'll have to try other routes to figure out how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it myself. Flex-container around the child div elements. Set flex control to column and specified a min-height for the top child when fully expanded.

Result: both child divs are fully responsive and shrink or grow to fill parent depending on each others needs.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 flex-container">

<ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="width:100%; height:325px">

.flex-container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
width: 260px;
padding-right: 0px;
height: 400px;
align-items: stretch;
}
```